# Why am I getting "Invalid argument to function" and "Enter parameter value" when running my access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, subquery, ms-access-2010

I have a list of record:

```
UniqueID  
110000  
110000  
110001  
110002  
110002  
110002
```

And want to get result of how many times each record shows, like:

```
UniqueID    times  
110000     1  
110000     2  
110001     1  
110002     1  
110002     2  
110002     3
```

My coding is like:

```
SELECT  m.UniqueID,  
(SELECT Count(*)   
From [Query1] AS m2   
Where m2.UniqueID =m.UniqueID And m2.Order1 <= m.Order1) AS COL2b  
FROM [Query1] AS m;
```

This would give me a result of "Invalid argument to function" and the code works if I remove argument of order1 like

```
SELECT  m.UniqueID,  
(SELECT Count(*)   
From [Query1] AS m2   
Where m2.UniqueID =m.UniqueID) AS COL2b  
FROM [Query1] AS m;
```

And if I change the code to count(B.Num1) and create a new query, the code would give me a result of "Enter parameter value A.Order1" like:

```
SELECT A.UniqueID, (Select Count(B.Num1)
From [Query1] As B
Where B.UniqueID = A.UniqueID AND B.Order1 <= A.Order1) AS COL2b
FROM [Query1] AS A
ORDER BY A.UniqueID;
```

I'm sure there is problem about the Order1 field or the access. How Can I fix it?

---

For reference, Num1 is a list of 1.
Query1 looks like

```
UniqueID    Num1  Order1
110000     1       1
110000     1       2
110001     1       3
110002     1       4
110002     1       5
110002     1       6
```

and the access sql code for query 1 is:

```
SELECT A.UniqueID, A.Num1, (Select Count(B.Num1)
From [TableRecords] As B
Where B.UniqueID <= A.UniqueID) AS Order1
FROM [TableRecords] AS A
ORDER BY A.UniqueID;
```

Comment: First, something called `uniqueid` should not be repeated on separate rows.  Second, if you only have one column, this is very hard in MS Access.  Do you have any other columns?

Comment: There is another column "Inflow" on the original table but is not used here. Sorry for the "UniqueID". It's just the naming problem. You can just take it account id.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like:

```
SELECT a.UniqueId, count(a.uniqueId)
FROM Table a
GROUP BY a.uniqueId
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I get the cumulative count from there?

Comment: Why would you want to see the count per row? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: The "Group By" will group all of the ones with the same id and give you the count of how many rows have that same id.

Answer (score 0):

Try analytical functions. Something like this:

```
select UniqueID
, row_number() over(partition by UniqueID order by UniqueID) times
from query1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet (apart from changing databases) is:

```
SELECT m.UniqueID,  
       (SELECT Count(*)   
        FROM [Query1] AS m2   
        WHERE m2.UniqueID = m.UniqueID AND
              m2.inflow <= m.inflow
       ) AS COL2b  
FROM [Query1] AS m;
```

This assumes that `inflow` is unique for each `uniqueid`.

If this doesn't work, then you can copy the data into a new table that has an auto number column.  You can use the auto number column instead of `inflow`.